# Transform Django Annotate Output

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my application, I have the following annotation statement:

```
TestQuestion.objects.filter(test__owner=self.user, test__complete=True).values('question__concept__name', 'chosen_answer__is_correct').annotate(dcount=Count('question__concept__name'))
```

Which returns a JSON output like follows:

```
"concept_questions_completed": [
        {
            "question__concept__name": "Math",
            "chosen_answer__is_correct": false,
            "dcount": 8
        },
        {
            "question__concept__name": "Math",
            "chosen_answer__is_correct": true,
            "dcount": 9
        },
.....
    ]
```

However, wonder if there is any way to transform the output to make it easier to work with later. Such that it would look something like this:

```
"concept_questions_completed": [
     "Math": 
        {
            true:
            { 
                "dcount": 9
            },
            false:
             { 
                "dcount": 8
            }
        },
        ...
    ]
```

Comment: you will have to parse the data and convert to your desirable format

Comment: To make such output means you've to query it accordingly; even though I feel getting true: { "dcount": 9 } will be difficult; closest will be "true": {"dcount": 9 } and so on ..

This will also mean that; you will have to query for each question and for each true and false.

Question: Do you want your SQL to heavylift or python code to parse it will be a wise question